# SQLite cannot update multiple tables at once

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sql-update

```
UPDATE X, Y
SET X.3="Updated String", Y.3="Updated String"
WHERE X.1 = Y.1
AND X.2 = Y.2;
```

The query above is working fine with MySQL. I'm having problems migrating it to SQLite as SQLite doesn't support multiple tables update at once (Subquerying might work, but I have no idea how to do it). I am trying to run this query using python's sqlite3 module.

Please consider X and Y as tables with columns 1,2,3.

Can anyone help me in this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This can't be done in SQLite.

Comment: Is there any alternative? Using join. If so, can you help?

Comment: Multi table update is not supported by SQLite. It can be done only with 2 separate update statements.

Comment: Can I just update one single table(UPDATE X), but comparing 2 tables(WHERE X.1 = Y.1)?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, but it requires trickiness. Make a view that joins the tables of interest (I assume that's a sensible thing to do) and set an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger on the view. Trigger programs can modify multiple different tables.

```
CREATE VIEW xy AS 
    SELECT X.3 AS x3, Y.3 AS y3, X.1 AS x1, X.2 AS x2 
    FROM X JOIN Y ON X.1 = Y.1 AND X.2 = Y.2;

CREATE TRIGGER xy_update
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON xy
BEGIN
    UPDATE X SET X.3 = NEW.x3 WHERE X.1 = NEW.x1 AND X.2 = NEW.x2;
    UPDATE Y SET Y.3 = NEW.x3 WHERE Y.1 = NEW.x1 AND Y.2 = NEW.x2;
END;
```

Then you can do this:

```
UPDATE xy SET x3 = 'Updated String', y3 = 'Updated String';
-- No select required, but you can add one if you want
```

If you only need this for a short while, consider making `xy` and its trigger be `TEMPORARY`.

Answer (score 3):

Multi table updates are not supported by SQLite.
It can be done only with 2 separate update statements:

```
UPDATE X
SET X.3 = 'Updated String'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Y WHERE X.1 = Y.1 AND X.2 = Y.2);

UPDATE Y
SET Y.3 = 'Updated String'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM X WHERE X.1 = Y.1 AND X.2 = Y.2);
```